# Type expression for a tuple representing arguments to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm looking for a way to create a type expression for a std::tuple representing the arguments required by a function. Consider the following:

```
template<typename F, typename ...args>
void myfunction(F&& function, A... args)
{
    std::tuple</*???*/> arguments;
    populate_tuple(arguments,args...);
    return apply(function,arguments);
}
```

... where F is a normal function type, apply() is a function that applies the arguments to the function, and populate_tuple() does some work on the arguments (including type conversions) before populating the tuple with the final arguments for the call to the function.

**Note:** I can't use `args...` in the declaration of the tuple, because these are *not* the types that the function is expecting - populate_tuple() does the conversion.

It feels to me as though the compiler has everything it needs to do this, but I don't know if the language supports it. Any ideas? All help appreciated.

Comment: How about change `populate_tuple` to return the tuple you need and in the `myfunction` use `auto`, like `auto arguments = populate_tuple(args...);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T> struct TupleOfArguments;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct TupleOfArguments<R(Args...)> {
  typedef std::tuple<Args...> type;
};
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IKHWP52173)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void myfunction(F&& function, Args&&... args) {
     return apply(std::forward<F>(function), std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```